# getBetween two strings on a specific page?

Tags: java, string, methods

I currently have a getBetween function like so:

```
public static String getBetween(String haystack, String pre, String post) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(pre+"(.+?)"+post);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(haystack);
    if(matcher.find())
        return haystack.substring(matcher.start(1),matcher.end(1));
    return "No match could be found.";
}
```

And when I try to getBetween two strings that have "s in them, it wont work.

Like:

`System.out.println(getBetween(strHTML, "href="/objects.phtml?type=inventory">", "</a> <span style="font-weight: normal;">"));`

Is there any way for me to parse the two strings so it will work with the "s and still beable to work with getBetween()?

Comment: Use a parser for parsing html

Comment: Is there something in Java that is not third-party that can do this? I'm not used to complex java things :/

Comment: You could try indexOf() and substring(), both are part of String. Still this could fail and of course its slow, but give it a try.

Comment: My current problem is that since there are "s in the code I am "gettingBetween", Java will not allow it :/

Comment: While that works for getting rid of the error, it causes it not to be found in the strHTML. :(

Comment: It sometimes works, sometimes does not. I'm not quite sure if its the getBetween method or Java not liking "s

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want somewhere in the middle of `strHTML` to be printed out? The issue is your `pre` and `post` that get compile, I think the html has different meaning than the one in Java Pattern. So you will need to quote them.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class GetBetween
{

    public static String getBetween(String haystack, String pre, String post)
    {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile( Pattern.quote(pre) + "(.+?)" + Pattern.quote(post));
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(haystack);

        if (matcher.find())
        {
            return haystack.substring(matcher.start(1),matcher.end(1));
        }

        return "No match could be found.";
    }


    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String strHTML = "href=\"/objects.phtml?type=inventory\">\"s</a><span style=\"font-weight: normal;\">";

        System.out.println(getBetween(strHTML, "href=\"/objects.phtml?type=inventory\">", "</a><span style=\"font-weight: normal;\">"));

       strHTML = "href=\"/objects.phtml?type=inventory\"></a><span style=\"font-weight: normal;\">";

        System.out.println(getBetween(strHTML, "href=\"/objects.phtml?type=inventory\">", "</a><span style=\"font-weight: normal;\">"));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
int startIndex = haystack.indexOf(pre);
// handle the case where startIndex is -1
int endIndex = haystack.indexOf(startIndex, post);
// handle the case where endIndex is -1
return haystack.substring(startIndex, endIndex)
```